# Notebook Shuts Down when i close the lid

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

Recently i bought [this notebook](http://www.monsternotebook.com.tr/W251ESQ-GT630M-MONSTER%C2%AE-Q61W251ESQ01.html). After i install Windows i made my default power settings. As in my settings, it should sleep in all conditions; Power button, sleep button, Closing lid.

However the problem is when i intend to start using my notebook again after closing lid, i noticed that it is closed instead of sleep mode. I am facin that windows loadin page which prompts me that my computer is not closed properly. Start windows as usual (or something like that in english) And the worst part; all my tabs, browsers, works will be closed too.

Since closing lid is my habit, i need to solve this problem. Why does it override my choice or what is going wrong?

My windows is: Win7 64bit Home Premium

(I usually dont close tabs or my works for days.)

Comment: have you checked the settings in `Power options`?

Comment: Yes, i did. It was all seem ok. But i figured out "sleep" only was not enough. "Hibernate" also effects the "sleep" option. So i turned it on. Answered under question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. When Hibernation is off the problem occurs and shuts everything.
To open hibernation on your computer do the following.

1. Press start Type **CMD** to search.
2. Right click **cmd.exe** and click **"Run as an administrator"**
3. Type this and press enter: `powercfg /hibernate on`
4. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you did not mention is if sleep has ever worked. Does it work by any other means than closing the lid?

**Here are some things to try;**

Make sure all hardware drivers are up to date and you have all Windows Updates. Also, check for a BIOS update from the manufacturer.

If the problem still exists, it is possible there might be some incompatibility between your hardware and Windows 7 sleep capabilities. Here is an article, [About how to troubleshoot power plans in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980869), which may help you find the issue.

Comment: I did not mention of that because i noted that i bought it recently. So i didn't ever make it work so far. But i solved the situation and posted as answer. Thanks for your help.