# Make windows honor my setting to do nothing when I close the lid of my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, sleep

My Windows Version 10.0.15063 computer (Dell Precision 5520) will go to sleep when I close the lid, even though in the settings I have specified to do nothing. See image:

[image: windows 10 power options]

I've tried restarting my computer and toggling it, and creating my own power profile. The setting persists but windows is not honoring it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate...https://superuser.com/questions/459810/notebook-shuts-down-when-i-close-the-lid?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that the setting in the control panel is not changing the attribute in the registry. This could be due to a group policy, a third party power management tool, or a windows bug.

1. run the following command in a cmd prompt to see what power settings are being honored by your system: `PowerCfg /q`
2. Find the [GUID](https://bitsum.com/known-windows-power-guids/) setting for closing your lid. For me its

   > Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347
   >   Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936
   >   [image]
   >   Notice the current setting is 1. That means it will sleep when the lid is closed.
3. Open regedit. (You can search for it in the start menu)
4. Go to the following entry: 
   `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936`
5. Change the `Attributes` Key to have a DWORD value of `0`
6. If you want to change the other power profiles you can go into the `DefaultPowerSchemeValues` subfolder and change those `Attributes` values to be `0` as well

Comment: After step 5, I also had to change my settings back and forth for both "On Battery" and "Plugged In". Once I changed these both to "Do Nothing", then I could change "On Battery" back to "Hibernate", and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is technically correct, however, I found an additional thing I had to do to actually stop my laptop from entering sleep mode.

I had previously selected the Performance power plan, but recently discovered there were a few options not being honored. So just on a whim, I thought I would try setting my laptop back to the Balanced power plan and adjsuting its settings to suit my needs. Lo and behold the settings all of a sudden all started being honored. I also noted that the previously selected Performance power plan disappeared from my list of power plan options. So it would appear one of the recent Windows Updates has potentially removed the Performance power plan from the default list of options, and I assume therefore only offering partial backwards compatibility.

Hope this helps anybody still struggling with this annoying behavioural glitch.

Comment: Yes, I have since noticed that as well. Thanks for posting this helpful guidance